# Java, displaying change in coins, arrays, functions?

Tags: java, arrays, function

My function ReturnChange is supposed to take in change, coins array (int Coins[] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 5};) p.s they are in cents,  and numCoins array (int NumCoins[] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10};) and calculate the change. The change should be in coins. If coins finish i.e num coins than alternative coins have to be used.

```
private static int ReturnChange(double change, int[] Coins, int[] numCoins) {

    int i = 0;
    int totalcoins = 0;
    change = change * 100;
    do {

        totalcoins++;
        change -= 100;

    } while (change >= 100);
    System.out.println("1 dollar x " + totalcoins + "");
    i++;
    int coinsfifty = 0;
    do {
        coinsfifty++;
        change -= 50;

    } while (change >= 50);
    System.out.println("50 cents x " + coinsfifty + "");
    i++;
    int coinstwenty = 0;
    do {
        coinstwenty++;
        change -= 20;

    } while (change >= 20);
    System.out.println("20 cent x " + coinstwenty + "");
    i++;
    int coinsten = 0;
    do {
        coinsten++;
        change -= 10;

    } while (change >= 10);
    System.out.println("10 cent x " + coinsten + "");
    i++;
    int coinsfive = 0;
    do {

        coinsfive++;
        change -= 5;
    } while (change >= 5);
    System.out.println("5 cent x " + coinsfive + "");
    return 0;

}
```

the output when 4 is passed as change is :

> 1 dollar x 4
>   50 cents x 1
>   20 cent x 1
>   10 cent x 1
>   5 cent x 1

the output when 2.5 as example is passed in change:

> 1 dollar x 2
>   50 cents x 1
>   20 cent x 1
>   10 cent x 1
>   5 cent x 1

The problem:
Need the others such as 50 cents etc to display zero in output 1, and display 0 for 20 cent onwards in output 2 and not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you shouldnt've used do-while.

It's logically wrong since the code inside 'do' always runs at least once.

Simply replace your do-whiles with while like:

```
do {
    totalcoins++;
    change -= 100;
} while (change >= 100);
```

to

```
while(change >= 100) {
    totalcoins++;
    change -= 100;
}
```

Comment: i swear i used while it didnt work, i used it again after u mentioned it it works!!! i think i  didnt remove the semi colon. thanks for yuor reply. may god increase your knowledge.